# Spring REST returns recursive JSON when bidirectional JPA mappings

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, recursion, fetch

I created a Bidirectional JPA One to Many mapping with two tables. Lazy fetch added to both sides. When I call for getting one side of data, persistent layer returns a correct result set without relationships. 
But when get those data through a REST API, It returns a long JSON object. ( Recursive data).

Java 8, Spring boot, Spring Data JPA

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_auction")
public class Auction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "auction_name")
    private String tenderName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tender")
    private Set<Bid> bids;

}

`` Bidding Entity ---------------

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_bid")
public class Bid {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "bid_date")
    private Date bidDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tender_join_id")
    private Tender tender;
}

`` Service Class ------------

public ResponseDto loadTenders(Tender tender) {
        ResponseDto responseDto = new ResponseDto();
        responseDto.setResponseItems(tenderRepository.findAll()); 
        return responseDto; // returns long JSON
    }

The actual result was a long JSON object.
The expected result is, Only requested entity without any mapped entities.
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Make sure that all of your entities implement `equals` and `hashCode`

**2)** If you are querying from the `Auction` to `Bid` then you can ignore the `Auction`:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "tender_join_id")
private Auction auction;
```

Just from my experience passing hibernate proxies directly to be parsed by the Jackson, just triggers a lot of problems like that. You may want to think about some sort of DTO with mappers layer. Just an advice, decision is up to you.